# How to change IE modes in Microsoft Edge

Tags: internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I am running Windows 8.1 and I needed to test a website in Edge and so I switched to a friend's PC with Windows 10 and tried Edge. But when I wanted to switch between mode such as IE 8,9,10,11, I am unable to. Instead I see the following screen:

[image]

I don't understand where should I switch modes. In IE 11 it's easy to find, but I am not so sure about Edge. What can I try next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't use Microsoft Edge to test sites on Internet Explorer. You do so from within Internet Explorer. You can jump to IE from Microsoft Edge by clicking on the "..." at the top right and choosing Open with Internet Explorer.

Comment: Ohh Thanks superstar ! :)